# Node graceful shutdown - destroy inactive keepAlive connections but complete ongoing requests

Tags: node.js, express

I'm struggling with implementing a graceful shutdown in NodeJS.

My definition of graceful:
**upon receiving SIGINT, the server stops accepting new connections, completes all active requests, then immediately kills all keepalive connections and the process exits.**

```
const express = require('express');
// const enableDestroy = require('server-destroy'); // approach 2
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    setTimeout(() => { 
        res.send('Hello World!')        
        // req.connection.destroy(); // approach 3
    }, 5000)    
});

const server = require('http').createServer(app)
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`HelloWorld listening on port ${port}`))

// enableDestroy(server) // approach 2

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  console.log('\nSIGINT received...')
  // server.destroy() // approach 2
  server.close(() => { console.log('Successfully closed all connections!') })  
});
```

**How to test:**
Run script above, hit http://localhost:5000/ in browser, terminate script above using CTRL+C while request is still running. Expected behavior: request is served, script terminates as soon as it's served.

Tried:

1. [godaddy/terminus](https://github.com/godaddy/terminus) **Result:** does nothing to kill keepalive connections, server.close takes forever (apparently, 120 seconds - the default request timeout value).
2. [server-destroy](https://github.com/isaacs/server-destroy) (I commented the exact lines). **Result**: kills ongoing requests, server.close() is instant but request fails.
3. calling *req.connection.destroy()* after every connection (I commented the exact line). **Result**: does nothing, server.close() takes forever (120 seconds).